# Next.js - How to hide navigation and footer component on 404 page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, http-status-code-404

```
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Layout({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      {router.pathname !== "/*" && <Navigation />}
      {/* {router.pathname !== "*" && <Navigation />} */}
      <main className="main-content">{children}</main>
      {router.pathname !== "/*" && <Footer />}
      {/* {router.pathname !== "*" && <Footer />} */}
    </>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Unfortunately the methods with an asterisk do not work :/ ?!?

Thank you in advance and best regards for everyone ;-)

Comment: if page is 404 or 500 pathname is always `/_error`  so `{router.pathname !== "/_error" && <Navigation />}`

Comment: Thanks Nico   One question additional What if we have custom 404 error page ?? I suppose there is another path....

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using a custom 404 page, the default `router.pathname` is `_error` so

```
{router.pathname !== "/_error" && <Navigation />}
```

should work.

If you are using custom 404 page (404.js inside `/pages`) `router.pathname` is `/404`.

If you reuse the [built in error page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page) `router.pathname` inside your page or component  `router.pathname` would be the current page path.
Ex :

```
import Error from 'next/error'

const MyPage = ({isError = true})=>{
    // pagepath would be something like pages/mypage
    return isError ?  <Error statusCode={"404"} /> : <p>My page </p>
}

export default MyPage
```

In this case both methods mentioned above wont work.
However i would not recommended to use this method.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Nico !  Everything seems to work perfect ! Best Regards 

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add this code to serve other people who encounter the same problem. In my case, when we have **custom** 404 page , the solution looks like this =>

```js
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Layout({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      {router.pathname !== "/404" && <Navigation />}
      <main className="main-content">{children}</main>
      {router.pathname !== "/404" && <Footer />}
    </>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```